# Subfield values in .NET Local Report

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-2.0, report

I'm attempting to use business objects as a datasource for an ASP.NET Microsoft rdlc Report and I am having problems displaying the values of subobjects in the report.

For example, if have the following two classes 'Customer' and 'Address'.

```
Customer
    FirstName
    LastName
    Address
    etc.

Address
    HomeAddress1 
    etc.
```

Customer contains an instance of Address. If I set a list of Customers as the report datasource, I can refer to the values of each customer in the report as follows:

```
=Fields!FirstName.Value
```

However, I can't work out how to refer to the values of the 'Address' sub-object. I had assumed one of the following would work:

```
=Fields!Address.HomeAddress1.Value
```

or

```
=Fields!Address!HomeAddress1.Value
```

But neither of these do. Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following syntax seems to work.

```
=Fields!Address.Value.HomeAddress1
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, and I'm sorry to say that I haven't found a way to reference sub-properties (I do hope that someone else has one though!)

What I ended up doing is creating a wrapper class that has all the properties I need directly in it.